# run-main-0) scala.ScalaReflectionException: class java.sql.Date in JavaMirror with ClasspathFilter(

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I have a file given to by my teacher. It is about Scala and Spark.
When I run the code it gives me this exception:

```
  (run-main-0) scala.ScalaReflectionException: class java.sql.Date in 
  JavaMirror with ClasspathFilter
```

The file itself looks like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
object Main {
   type Embedding       = (String, List[Double])
   type ParsedReview    = (Integer, String, Double)
   org.apache.log4j.Logger getLogger "org"  setLevel 
   (org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN)
   org.apache.log4j.Logger getLogger "akka" setLevel 
  (org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN)
   val spark =  SparkSession.builder
     .appName ("Sentiment")
     .master  ("local[9]")
     .getOrCreate

import spark.implicits._

val reviewSchema = StructType(Array(
        StructField ("reviewText", StringType, nullable=false),
        StructField ("overall",    DoubleType, nullable=false),
        StructField ("summary",    StringType, nullable=false)))

// Read file and merge the text abd summary into a single text column

def loadReviews (path: String): Dataset[ParsedReview] =
    spark
        .read
        .schema (reviewSchema)
        .json (path)
        .rdd
        .zipWithUniqueId
        .map[(Integer,String,Double)] { case (row,id) => (id.toInt, s"${row getString 2} ${row getString 0}", row getDouble 1) }
        .toDS
        .withColumnRenamed ("_1", "id" )
        .withColumnRenamed ("_2", "text")
        .withColumnRenamed ("_3", "overall")
        .as[ParsedReview]

 // Load the GLoVe embeddings file

 def loadGlove (path: String): Dataset[Embedding] =
     spark
         .read
         .text (path)
    .map  { _ getString 0 split " " }
    .map  (r => (r.head, r.tail.toList.map (_.toDouble))) // yuck!
         .withColumnRenamed ("_1", "word" )
         .withColumnRenamed ("_2", "vec")
         .as[Embedding]

def main(args: Array[String]) = {

  val glove  = loadGlove ("Data/glove.6B.50d.txt") // take glove 

  val reviews = loadReviews ("Data/Electronics_5.json") // FIXME

  // replace the following with the project code



   glove.show
   reviews.show

        spark.stop
   }

 }
```

I need to keep the line 
      import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
because some code depends on it but it is exactly because of it I have an exception throw.

My build.sbt file looks like this:

```
  name := "Sentiment Analysis Project"

  version := "1.1"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")

  initialCommands in console := 
  """
  import Main._
  """

   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"

   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % 
   "2.3.0"

    libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5"

    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % 
    "test"
```

Comment: Thanks. And which version of JDK do you use?

Comment: After i type in my terminal `java -version`.

Comment: I got as a result:

Comment: java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, which I found out to be the `read` method call.

Answer (score 1):

The Scala guide [recommends](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html) you compile with Java8:

> We recommend using Java 8 for compiling Scala code. Since the JVM is backward compatible, it is usually safe to use a newer JVM to run your code compiled by the Scala compiler for older JVM versions.

Although it's only a recommendation, I found it to fix the issue you mention.

In order to install Java 8 using Homebrew, it's best to use [jenv](http://www.jenv.be/) which will help you handle multiple Java versions should you need to.

```
brew install jenv
```

Then run the following to add a tap (repository) of alternative versions of casks, since Java 8 is not in the default tap anymore:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
```

To install Java 8:

```
brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

Run the following to add the previously installed Java version to `jenv`'s list of versions:

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<installed_java_version>/Contents/Home
```

Finally run

```
jenv global 1.8
```

or

```
jenv local 1.8
```

to use Java 1.8 globally or locally (in the current folder).

Fore more information, follow the instructions at [jenv's website](http://www.jenv.be/)